# Optimizing SHA-256 implementation for fixed input prefix

Tags: hash, sha-256

Is it possible to optimize/precalculate some results in SHA-256 if the input starts with fixed values? My input is always `1111||message`. Can I precalculate the `1111` in SHA-256 to save some cycles?

Answer (score 5):

You can't completely precalculate `1111`, however, you can completely precalculate messages that have a length multiple of 512. The reason is simple, SHA-256 uses 512-bit message block per compression, i.e. the compression function of SHA-256 uses 512-bit message inputs and 256-bit previous hash values.

$$C:\{0,1\}^{256}\times \{0,1\}^{512} \to \{0,1\}^{256}$$

and

$$H_i= C(H_{i-1},m_i)$$ where each $m_i$ has 512-bit lenght and $H_0$ is the [IV](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf).

---

**per comment** [below](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88257/optimizing-sha-256-implementation-for-fixed-input-prefix#comment194220_88259)

> To be honest, my input is 32-Byte ones || 32-Byte X || 32-Byte Y, what exactly do I have to precalculate with `X` is not constant?

32-Byte makes 256 bits, therefore you cannot completely precalculate one compression. However, still, you can pre-compute some rounds of the compression function it that helps;

The SHA-256 uses a block cipher with 64 rounds and each round uses the message as a key and you can calculate 8 rounds of the next compression call. The key $W_i$ for round $i$ is formed by the message words $M_t$ of the block is formed by;

$$W_i = \begin{cases}M_t^{(i)} & 0 \leq t \leq 15 \\
\sigma_0^{256} W_{t-2} + W_{t-7} + \sigma_1^{256}W_{t-15} + W_{t-16} &
16 \leq t \leq 63
\end{cases}$$

With the 32-byte you can precalculate only 8 rounds of the compression function. The `Y` has no such options since at the beginning of the rounds the previous hash value from the previous compression function is needed.

---

**using $11..11$ as a full block**:

There is one way, though not effective, one can calculate $H'=C(H_0,11..11)$. This will require padding. Now you can use this $H'$ as the $IV$ for the $\operatorname{SHA256'}$; That is

$$H_i= C(H_{i-1},m_i)$$ where each $m_i$ has 512-bit lenght and $H_0$ is the $H'$ then your real message becomes as

$$11..11 \mathbin\| padding_1 \mathbin\| X \mathbin\| Y \mathbin\| padding_2$$

Comment: to be honest, my input is 32-Byte ones || 32-Byte X || 32-Byte Y, what exactly do I have to precalculate in the SHA256 function?

Comment: the problem is, X is not constant

Comment: @alice03 it should be done now.

Comment: thanks, do you know if it is also possible to optimize SHAKE128 with this method?

Comment: @alice03 yes, and very little advantage, again. Well, since 11.11 is not private, See the updated method that may fit you.